# JQuery Mobile pages recognized as mobile version in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, cross-browser

I use JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 and the pages are recognized as mobile version (all vertical layout and all icons changed into mobile version icons) in IE 8. But they worked fine in IE 9-11 and other browsers(desktop layout).

How to prevent IE 8 recognizing those pages as mobile version?